Single Pane Windows - Anything besides replacing them?
I am in a nearly 50yo home. There's a 2 story room that has floor to ceiling single pane windows. There are 10 windows that are roughly 3' by 6' and another 4 that are roughly 3' by 4'. It will eventually be a very large and expensive project to replace all of them.
In the meantime - do I have any wintertime home improvement options?
I'm in Connecticut and the other night it was about 18°F outside and inside the window (between the glass and the shade) was 39°F. Brr. 

When you get to replacement, replacing with smaller (and better insulated) windows and more insulated wall area will make a big difference, while keeping your costs lower.

Heat shrink plastic sheet installed over the windows can do wonders. I've had great success using FrostKing Shrink Window Kits installed seasonally over a double door in a 1930 vintage house in New York. Single pane divided lites and terrible weatherstripping made doing something necessary.
It takes a little practice to get the taping reasonably even and shrinking the sheet to eliminate wrinkles. The result isn't invisible, but it's pretty hard to see.
It would be worth renting scaffolding, or hiring someone, to install the sheets. It is generally recommended that they be removed after the winter so that the tape does not cause permanent damage to the trim. You might not care about the upper windows and just leave them covered permanently.
Cellular, aka honeycomb, shades can also make a significant difference. They need to be fitted close to the window casing for best effect. Poorly installed they can optimize a chimney effect that causes even more heat loss. Good ones aren't inexpensive. They have to be closed to provide any insulating value and, of course, you lose the view when closed.
Disclaimer - No affiliation with FrostKing and I'm sure there are other brands that work quite well. Just a satisfied customer for a long time.

Thanks. We do have honeycomb blinds and they make a difference. Between the glass and the blinds it was below 40°F the other day and 64°F on the room side.

We use FK kits for the film but bought 3M tape for the taping. The film appeared to be equivalent between brands. At the time anyway, 3M's tape was a lot better. We got FK's tape because it came with their kit, but we did not use it.

If you want the window function to be retained, the answer already suggesting the clear heat shrink film is the best way to do that quickly and affordably.
If you want much better insulation and are willing to give up window function, (or are willing to give it up on some of the windows) "movable window insulation" is a way to do that.
Expensive and overly fussy to keep operating correctly would be something like the Window Quilt system (no endorsement - I have considerable experience with the "overly fussy" aspect on a pre-existing set of those, since junked when the windows were replaced with smaller and better insulated ones) of insulated blinds that are sealed to the sides (and have a seal of sorts at the top and bottom as well) of the windows. Those (when functioning) can be pulled down at night and opened during the day if you want light; and are far more effective than free-hanging drapes at insulating the window. Perhaps some improvements have been made - the ones I had experience with were nearly the same vintage as your house. They kept getting jammed so they were hard to open and close reliably.
Rigid foam (typically with a decorative and hopefully also flame-retardant fabric covering) cut for a jam-fit in the windowframe is more difficult to move, but also offers a lot (like 5-10x) more insulation value. In the room illustrated I'd expect the top window insulation to be in place all winter, and you might move some panels of the bottom windows on a sunny day when you were home. Or you might only use them on the top and use film on the lower windows, or use film on half the lower windows and panels on half the lower windows. That partly depends on how much you use the room during the short daylight of winter.

This is the type of out-of-the-box suggestion I was hoping for.
And you are right, I raise the lower blinds in the winter to let the sun (and heat in) and haven't touched the top ones at all. They'll probably stay closed a lot during the peak of summer as well (to keep the heat ut).

Heavy plastic sealed well with tape over the inside of the windows and heavy drapes that you keep closed all the time, help hold the cold air toward the windows and keep the room a bit warmer.
Otherwise, as you know you need to replace the windows with more energy efficient ones.

Thanks - that might be a good idea for the lower windows.
But the top windows start at about 8' and go up to 14'=15' and it's too hard to get up there.
I'm honestly not sure what I am hoping for here. But I do appreciate any suggestions.

Even if you can't afford to replace the windows at the moment, surely you can afford the $31 it costs to rent one of those adjustable ladders from Home Depot for an afternoon.

For those size panes, to get the film on right is a two person operation.

The question was " do I have any wintertime home improvement options?".  Not "what can I do that does not require any work or a ladder."

You do not say what direction these windows face.
For the upper windows, a short term solution is installing interior glass\UV
stable plexiglass panels if space permits. The only drawback is that things have to be optically perfect at installation because you will be living with the consequences until you can't stand it. This should give you R2 for the insulating value, a 50% improvement.
For the future, if you do decide to replace the windows and they happen to face North, consider buying windows which have a U factor of at least .2 (R-5). This greatly eliminates the feeling of heat being sucked out of you when you are standing next to the window. This will not be cheap given the current open glass areas involved.
On the other hand, if they are more oriented South, buy windows that have a Solar Heat Gain Coefficient of around .5 to balance the benefit of solar gain in winter while not being roasted out in the summer.
